# How to wrap a input element within a div

Tags: html, css, slider

I am building a website which allows the user to change tempurature .

To change tempurature value, I want to use a range slider, but the problem is that the the slider doesn't fit inside a wrapping div.

This is my html :

```
<div class="col" id="controls">
     <div class="sectionTitle">    
          <span>Controls</span>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
           <div class="controlTitle">
                 place holder
           </div>
            <div>
                <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" /> 
            </div>      
       </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.slider {
    width: 130px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 1px;  
    background: rgb(87, 101, 226);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(87, 101, 226);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .control{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
   }
```

Now what I am getting is that the slider gets out of the file stream, and resulting this : https://drive.google.com/open?id=19bsV2Bmd_xuJDwO0Z7eUhmtYEE3xdrTN

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are rotating the slider to make it vertical, is this the look you are going for? if not, couldn't you remove that bit of code?

```
.slider {
    width: 130px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 1px;  
    background: rgb(87, 101, 226);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    transform: rotate(90deg); //remove this line
  }
```

Comment: Hi Richard, yeah I wanna it to be vertical, because later I wanna add more vertical sliders next to it.